How do I use Automator to open an application with a file
I often find myself opening files such as .plist or .json files, etc., as plain text files for viewing in TextEdit. But often I need to follow Open With > Other… and then find TextEdit in the pop-up menu.
My solution is to create an Automator Quick Action, the file as input, and open TextEdit with the file, but the Launch Application action doesn’t take the file as input. Is there a roundabout way to do this?

The terminal command open can be used to open files with TextEdit if the -e flag is passed:
open "path_to_file" -e

Use the action Run Shell Script to run the following terminal command, changing Pass Input: to pass input as arguments:
for f in "$@"
do
     open "$f" -e
done

This runs the command open for each file you select in Finder, so you can even open multiple files at once.

FYI:  Just using for f does the same thing as for f in "$@".

Also, you probably could eliminate the loop entirely and just use this one line: open -e -- "$@"
